# Which data format is better for WebApps client«»server communication: HTML, XML, JSON, JSONP?

Tags: html, json, xml, jsonp

In which format is client server communication carried out?  Which is best option and why?  When a static *HTML* page is deployed at server, and the user/client accesses the page, how it is called?  Is this using *xml/json* or there are other formats too?

Answer (score 0):

Typically when a static HTML page is retrieved from a web server or application server, it happens over HTTP, with a MIME type of text/html. So it is neither XML nor JSON, although strict HTML often is a subset of strict XML, so in a sense you could say it is XML. But the MIME type is not text/xml, and certainly not application/json.

That being said, often a dynamic web page is served up as a combination of HTML, JavaScript, CSS, JSON data, XML data, and more, any or all of which might be delivered on the first page load or subsequent AJAX requests.

In many of those cases, special protocols can be used to transmit the data more effectively, or use connections or requests more efficiently.

Many developers favor the use of JSON for representing data being served up by web applications, because many web applications use JavaScript to organize data both client-side (in the browser) and server-side (on the web or application server), and JavaScript historically made it very easy to parse and utilize JSON data. But in recent years, there are usually plenty of standard libraries or language features for parsing JSON, XML, and other formats, such that the choice of JSON and XML can sometimes come down to developer preference, or concerns like request/response bloat (which one is fewer bytes), human readability (which one is easier for a human to understand), etc.